# Measurability of set of points where a measurable function sequence is strictly increasing pointwise

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself. How do we show that the set

$S=\{x\in\mathbb{R} \,\, |\,\, \{f_n(x)\} \,\text{is strictly increasing}\}$ is a measurable set?

I think we need to write the set as a union and intersection of inverse images of $f_n$'s but I have no idea how to proceed. Please drop some hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $S$ is measurable.

Define $A_n=\{x| f_{n+1}(x) -f_n(x)>0)\}$. Then $S=\bigcap_{n\geq 1} A_{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{f_{n+1}>f_n\}$$

If the $f_n$ are measurable then the sets $\{f_{n+1}>f_n\}$ are measurable.